# Print a row number or counter along with each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'd like to print the names of all the tables in my database but with a row number like so:

```
S.No.  Table Name
-------------------
1.     Products
2.     Orders
3.     OrderDetails
...
```

I tried the following but that gives me the total number of rows.

```
-- USE [MyDatabase]; -- implied

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS [S.No.], 
       Name as [Table Name] 
FROM Sys.Tables;
```

I figure I have to do something like:

```
@Counter int;
SELECT (SELECT ++@Counter AS [S.No.]), 
       Name AS [Table Name]
FROM Sys.Tables;
```

But I'm not quite sure of the exact syntax. Could you please help me with that?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as [S.No.], 
       Name as [Table Name] 
FROM Sys.Tables;
```